# detect build error Incompatible classes were found in dependencies in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

it seems like a build or gradle setting error. Any thought of how to fix it?

> [   +1 ms] e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove
> them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to
> suppress errors

Answer (score 1):

Change kotlin version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
```

che[image]ck your kotlin version in warning section

Answer (score 0):

This error will normally happen when the Kotlin version specified in your Android 'build.gradle' file is different from that bundled in Android Studio (or your preferred IDE in this case).

**To solve it:**
In Project Explorer of your Flutter project, navigate to `android` directory, and open `build.gradle` file.
**NOTE:** This is the overall 'build.gradle' file. Not the one inside the 'app' directory.

Your `build.gradle` file would look almost similar to the following snippet.

```html
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Your Kotlin version is marked by this line `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'`.
This version needs to be same as the version of Kotlin bundled in the IDE. You can find the version of the bundled Kotlin by opening the 'Problems' tool window (can normally be found on the bottom left in Android Studio).

Update the version, and re-run the Flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I made a new flutter project. and copied the version of ext.kotlin_version in the new project and pasted it. It worked perfectly for me.
My version is 1.6.10